# Migrating from v1 to v3 - Can't find or automatically infer mapping model for migration

Tags: cocoa, core-data

If I migrate from v1 to v2, then from v2 to v3 with it works. But If i migrate directly from v1 to v3 I get the Can't find our automatically infer mapping model for migration error.

I changed all the field names of v3, so in the mapping model I had to explicitly set the Value Expression for all Destination Attributes. I don't know if this can contribute to the problem.

What am I missing?

I'm using the following keys for migration:

```
  return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:

     [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,

     [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

The key issue is NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, since I was using this option I was not noticing that when the database upgrades version and does not find a mapping model, it tries to infer it. And since I did not have a mapping model with the data model source v1 to source v3. It would fail because it could not infer it since I changed the names of the attributes.